# net/http: TLS handshake timeout while login to Azure container registry from ubuntu

Tags: azure, docker, containers, tls1.2, acr

I'm trying to push an image to Azure container registry but before pushing an image when I tried to login to azure container registry login server, I'm getting below error
Error response from daemon: Get "https://newregistryforpoc.azurecr.io/v2/": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
My internet connection is fine.
Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually we will get this "TLS handshake timeout" Error, whenever docker Deamon proxy is not configured properly.

**Step1:**
Verify docker Deamon proxy configuration at

```
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/proxy.conf
```

**Step2:**
Flush changes once

```
sudo systemctl deamon-reload
```

**Step3:**
Restart docker

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Refer below [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy)  for more information.